# Docker container exits immediately after start

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I use `php:alpine` for my docker and build it successfully. But when I start it with `docker run --name=IMAGE_NAME -p 9000:80 -d -it -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /home/logs/:/home/logs/ TAG 'while true; do sleep 1000; done'`, it exits immediately. I check with `docker ps -a` and the command for it is `docker-php-entrypoint 'while true; do sleep 1000; done'`. How can I solve it?

Comment: I didn't think you could use -d and -i together?

Comment: It would make sense to provide a minimal example to simplify a task for anybody who wants to help. What I specifically mean is that most of the Docker options in your example are either redundant or not really used by your container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command line:

```
docker run --name=IMAGE_NAME -p 9000:80 -d -it -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /home/logs/:/home/logs/ TAG sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1000; done'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run docker logs -f  to see for what cause it's not starting.